# Making the xinput --set-button-map changes permanent

Tags: bluetooth, xinput

I have a new mouse which runs on bluetooth, but I had to setup the middle mouse button manually using `xinput --set-button-map`.  This isn't persistent after reboot, so I wrote a small python script to run it automatically after login.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work because there is some delay before the mouse automatically reconnects after login.

I thought of just adding some wait into my script, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.  Can I hook into connect events from `/usr/sbin/bluetoothd` or something like that instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I put some wait time and retries into my script and lived with that for a few days, but this weekend I had some spare time to find the "correct" solution.

That is, add the button map into a config file for X.

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/logitech-mx-revolution.conf

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Logitech MX Revolution Mouse"
    Option  "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 10 11 12 13 14 15 2 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24"
EndSection
```

Hopefully this helps someone else one day.

Comment: User Configuration is supposed to go to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

Comment: @user56452 actually, since 10.10, [Ubuntu does use `/usr/share/`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) for X11 user config. (I thought the same thing, actually, so I proposed an edit for this answer. Then 3 seconds later I found that wiki page. oops!)

Comment: @AustinAdams i dont see it. from that link:
Users can continue making custom configuration in /etc/xorg.conf as usual; the .conf snippets are mainly there for the distro or hw vendor to ship default InputClass rules and custom overrides. "

Comment: @user56452 well, this is doubly embarrassing -- you're right! On a 14.04 machine, I created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, and Xorg applied [a config file](http://ix.io/jWF) I placed there. (why did I doubt the manpage?!) The question, then, is if `/etc/` is a better choice for user configuration than `/usr/share/`. In principle, I'd say "absolutely," but I don't use Ubuntu. What do you think, @wim?

Comment: I think it's an inconsequential and trivial aspect of the issue.  It seems like either location works - if `/usr/share/X11` ever stops working someone can feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: It specifically says it's prone to be overwritten. 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.

Comment: @VirtualDXS  Not for me.  I created the file.

Comment: Thanks! That was the only way that was persistent over standby/resume for me - putting it in `.xsession` etc only worked on login, but was reset to defaults after resume

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech Ultrathin Touch and I got the remapping to work with:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf 
    #
    #  custom for logitech ultrathin mouse

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "Logitech bluetooth Touch Mouse"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "Name"   "Ultrathin Touch Mouse"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 1 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Ultrathin Touch Mouse"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 1 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Not sure if all of this is needed but after a day of wrestling with this i'm just relieved that something works...
I've found now that horizontal scrolling is a little slower than i'd like. so i'll probably see if there's some option to configure that.