# How to reset xinput touchpad settings?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, xinput

I tried to change my touchpad settings by using these commands:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Noise Cancellation" 20 20
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 50 90 255
```

but then I have to press much harder for touchpad to work.
Is it possible to reset these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All what you have to do is a system reset(reboot) since all done by `xinput` is not permanent, which means all of your work is gone when you reboot, so you just have to do that.

To make xinput permanent refer to those:

- [How to make xinput settings persist after devices are unplugged, replugged, and after shutdown, restart, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20298/how-to-make-xinput-settings-persist-after-devices-are-unplugged-replugged-and)
- [How to Make an xinput Command Persistent After Standby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310729/how-to-make-an-xinput-command-persistent-after-standby)
- [Making the xinput --set-button-map changes permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405073/making-the-xinput-set-button-map-changes-permanent)

Comment: What if one doesn't want to reboot, i.e. if you are in the middle of some work?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I've found is to disconnect and then reconnect the device.  Remember that if this is a wireless mouse or the like, you'll likely need to disconnect the dongle or Bluetooth device and then reconnect/add it.

Comment: How is this answer better than the accepted one from five years ago?